# Howto include an "includes" file in html?

Tags: javascript, html

We are migrating an (classic) .asp application to html (and javascript). In the current .asp pages we use:

```
<!--#include virtual="/basefiles/allIncludes.asp" -->
```

We use this in all of or (about) 100 pages

allinclude.asp looks like this:

```
<!-- base JS-files -->
<script src="/basefiles/libraries/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/basefiles/libraries/adal.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/basefiles/libraries/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="/basefiles/PP.js"></script>

<!-- UI JS-files -->
<script src="/basefiles/libraries/fabric.min.js"></script>
etc....
```

Now we want to convert our .asp files to .html files but, this might look like a simple question but we cannot get this include construction working.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: "What is the best way to achieve this?" — Stick with ASP, or find another server-side language or static site builder. Doing this with client-side JS has too many drawbacks.

Comment: HTML file is a static file. It does not allow to include anything. You can use JS to render additional resources, but user can have JS disabled, it introduces additional HTTP requests too.

Comment: Could PHP be your alternative for ASP?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you can't include files with .html ending.. but you can use the ending .shtml or .php :)

if you use .php you will need to make it like this:

```
<?php include("/basefiles/allIncludes.php"); ?>
```

if you want to use shtml its like you wrote:

```
<!--#include virtual="/basefiles/allIncludes.shtml" -->
```

Comment: I do not need .asp or php. I want to migrate to client-side scripting which, in our case, is possible. But we need the include part. As asp is outdated we want to migrate to something more modern. Is SHTML modern or is this also outdated?

Comment: if you dont want to use php use shtml.. you can google it: it is for SSI (Server Side Includes) which means, you can include files like header, footer and so on on each page, so thats exactly what you are looking for ;) I just stated PHP, as you can use it also for including files with your js files in it)

Comment: so that means you will have your 100 pages now with index.html, about.html ... and then include your allIncludes via the shtml command I've wrote!

Comment: @hacking_mike — SSI (which sometimes uses .shtml file extensions) is a server-side technology that predates ASP.

Comment: Maybe I should just rename my .asp files to .aspx although I do not need server-side code. At least I am (webserver wise) on the latest technology. Or is there something wrong in this argumentation?